# sqlite: online backup is not identical to original

Tags: sqlite

I'm doing an online backup of an (idle) database using the example 2 code from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html). The backup file is not identical to the original (the length is the same, but it differs in 3 bytes), although the `.dump` from both databases is identical. Backup files taken at different times are identical to each other.

This isn't great, as I'd like a simple guarantee that the backup is identical to the original, and I'd like to record checksums on the actual database and the backups to simplify restores. Any idea if I can get around this, or if I can use the backup API to generate files that compare identically?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to ensure that the files are exactly the same. Just because the database files are different doesn't mean that they have different contents; one might have more free pages than the other, the pages may be reordered, etc.

Comment: Which bytes? offset 24?

Comment: Bytes 27, 28, and 44 were 22, 154, and 4 in the original, and ended up as 0, 1, and 1 (all decimal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online backup can write into an existing database, so this writing is done inside a transaction.
At the end of such a transaction, the file change counter (offsets 24-27) is changed to allow other processes to detect that the database was modified and that any caches in those processes are invalid.
This change counter does not use the value from the original database because it might be identical to the old value of the destination database.

If the destination database is freshly created, the change counter starts at zero.
This is likely to be a change from the original database, but at least it's consistent.

The byte at offset 28 was decreased because the database has some unused pages.
The byte at offset 44 was changed because the database does not actually use new schema features.
You might be able to avoid these changes by doing a VACUUM before the backup, but this wouldn't help for the change counter.

Comment: Thanks. This makes me think that (a) backing up a database with a manual copy maybe isn't such a bad idea after all, and (b) perhaps the backup API should have an option to keep the change counter/etc unchanged.

Comment: The backup API works database-to-database, not file-to-file. You could just copy the file, if you lock it with [BEGIN EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would not have expected them to be identical, just because the backup API ensures that any backups are self consistent (ie transactions in progress are ignored).

Comment: Well, yes, but I did say that the database was idle.